# .NET View.CustomSort exception 'Cannot call StartAt when content generation is in progress'

Tags: c#

I am sorting a set of `IEnumerable<object>`(which a WPF treeview's source is binded to)

I am casting this to a ListCollectionView (Where the 'entities' are my `IEnumerable<object>`)

```
ListCollectionView view = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(entities);
```

And then using a CustomSort with :

```
view.CustomSort = new NaturalStringComparerName();
```

The sorting works perfect the first time. However the second time I set the CustomSort it causes an exception "Cannot call StartAt when content generation is in progress".

My NaturalStringComparerName class:

```
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
internal static class SafeNativeMethods
{
    //PInvoke windows shlwapi dll (logical sorting, better than built in sorting)
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);
}

public sealed class NaturalStringComparerName : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object a, object b)
    {
        var A = (TblBase)a;
        var B = (TblBase)b;
        var Result = 0;
        try
        {
            if (A.Name == null)
                A.Name = "";
            if (B.Name == null)
                B.Name = "";
            Result = SafeNativeMethods.StrCmpLogicalW(A.Name, B.Name);
        }

        catch { }
        return Result;
    }
}
```

Any ideas what might be the cause of this?

Comment: Give more information. I undestood you're using WPF - yes? Why didn't you say that? What is your variable `entities`? What's the class `NaturalStringComparerName`?

Comment: @חייםפרידמן updated thank you

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: What line of code is showing the exception?